# create application paths with haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have a server running multiple web apps on different ports without any root application path. I can currently access them by, http://myServer:8001, http://myServer:8002, etc and I would like to access them via HaProxy as http://myServer/app1, http://myServer/app2, etc

I found multiple links using reqrep but i could not make it work. Here is my last attempt before I gave up:

```
frontend http-in
  option forwardfor
  bind *:80
  acl is-app1 path_beg /app1
  use_backend app1 if is-app1
  acl is-app2 path_beg /app2
  use_backend app2 if is-app2

backend app1
  reqrep ^Location:\ /app1/?(.*)     Location:\ /\1
  rsprep ^Location:\ (.*)     Location:\ /app1/\1
  server localhost 127.0.0.1:8001

backend app2
  reqrep ^Location:\ /app2/?(.*)     Location:\ /\1
  rsprep ^Location:\ (.*)     Location:\ /app2/\1
  server localhost 127.0.0.1:8002
```

From the examples i saw, i expected this single line to be enough (no need for rsprep), but i can't make it work.

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /app1/?(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

Comment: nobody has a clue? :(

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try - you may have to modify a little to suit your requirements.

```
frontend    http-in
    bind        *:80
    mode        http
    option      httplog
    option      dontlognull
    option      forwardfor

    # if "/app1"
    use_backend app1 if { path_beg /app1/ }

    # if "/app2"
    use_backend app2 if { path_beg /app2/ }

backend     app1
    reqrep      ^([^\ :]*)\ /app1/(.*) \1\ /\2
    option      forwardfor
    server      localhost 127.0.0.1:8001

backend     app2
    reqrep      ^([^\ :]*)\ /app2/(.*) \1\ /\2
    option      forwardfor
    server      localhost 127.0.0.1:8002
```